# Having trouble understanding Python with .enter() function

Tags: python

I am working out of the "Learn Python the Hard Way" book right now and I do not understand something. In one of the excersises the author uses some code I do not understand involving .enter()

```
def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
    last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(’finished’)

    while current_scene != last_scene:
        next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

    current_scene.enter()
```

I still don't totally understand classes, but I mostly understand what is going on here, save for enter. I can not find any documentation on it, and any information on why it is being used and why it is there would be very helpful. Thank you so much.

I am working out of exercises 43 in LPTHW from the newest edition. The specific part of the exercises is called Gothons from Planet Percal #25

Comment: Can you provide a link to the particular part of LPTHW you are referring to?

Comment: I added it at the bottom just now

Comment: Look up for opening_scene and it's class - it should be mentioned before or explained somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taught from LPTHW a few times.  The earlier answers are correct in the general solution.  **enter** is a method of each class that *you* have to design; this is why there's no documentation on it.  The purpose of this method is to do whatever you need to do when the player enters this room.  Typical implementations include:

- Print a welcome message
- Print a description of the room (what does the player "see"?)
- initialize other objects in the room, such as

  - Create a bear object
  - Determine the quantity of gold to be found
  - Update some game status, such as how many times the player has entered this room.

You're creating the world; the **enter** method is a significant part of presenting it to the player.

Have fun.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

enter() must be a function of the scene class (which is generated in the first function line). It is not an in-built Python functionality

Comment: That is completely right, I feel so stupid now. I was very much overthinking it. Thank you so much and very sorry for the bad question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be precise without looking at the full exercise, but I would imagine that `enter()` is simply a method of a class called `Scene` and `current_scene` is an instance of that class.

Comment: Also, from the text I saw online ,these seems like a terrible, terrible way to structure a game like that...

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can use pdb to debug your python application, just as below.

> python -m pdb your.py

In the pdb, you can use the command as below to find some information.

> help(current_scene.enter)

Comment: The poster is not trying to debug existing code; he's trying to figure out the purpose of the code to be used or written.

Comment: No no no. pdb is not only a debug tool. You can use it to comprehend the code. "Don't know the **enter** method"? Okay, "step in" in the pdb.

Comment: I'm not following: how does stepping into an empty routine help solve OPs problem?